How do I remove a subGrid filter on deselect of the related subGrid record? I have managed to filter the related subGrid onRecordSelect of main grid
'I have 2 subGrids on a form, the second of which filters based on record select of the first subGrid, however, on deselect of the record, the related subGrid filter remains. How do I remove this filter if the record is deselected? Mt code below for the filter:'
function subgridOnSelect(executionContext)
{
    var selected = executionContext.getFormContext().data.entity;
    var Id = selected.getId();
    formContext = window.ALLCONTEXT;
    
    if(Id != undefined && Id != null)
    {
        addSubgridEventListener(Id,formContext);
    }
    else
    {
        formContext.data.refresh();
    }
}

function addSubgridEventListener(recordid,formContext)
{
    var gridContext = formContext.getControl("subgrid_teamstemplatechannelfolders");
    //ensure that the subgrid is ready…if not wait and call this function again
    if (gridContext == null)
    {
        setTimeout(function () { addSubgridEventListener(recordid,formContext); }, 500);
        return;
    }
    //bind the event listener when the subgrid is ready

    var fetchxml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
                    "  <entity name='sis_teamstemplatechannelfolder'>" +
                    "    <attribute name='sis_channelnameid' />" +
                    "    <attribute name='sis_foldermembergroupid' />" +
                    "    <attribute name='sis_foldername' />" +
                    "    <attribute name='sis_parentfolderid' />" +
                    "    <attribute name='sis_teamstemplatechannelfolderid' />" +
                    "    <order attribute='sis_foldername' descending='false' />" +
                    "    <filter type='and'>" +
                    "      <condition attribute='sis_channelnameid' operator='eq' value='"+recordid+"' uiname='Teams Template Channel Test 1' uitype='sis_teamstemplatechannel' />" +
                    "    </filter>" +
                    "  </entity>" +
                    "</fetch>";

    gridContext.setFilterXml(fetchxml);
    gridContext.refresh();
}
ALLCONTEXT;
function Onload(executionContext)
{
    ALLCONTEXT = executionContext.getFormContext();
}

